# how to make video fit to screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

iwant to make a fullscreen video

lately i use an image as a cover but i change my mind and i want to use video
https://jsfiddle.net/fpjqh822/10/

thats my old code

and heres my video code

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<video  controls poster="http://www.webestools.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.png">
    <source src="http://www.webestools.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>

<div id="body2">lorem ipusm dolor sue lorem ipusm dolor sue lorem ipusm dolor sue lorem ipusm dolor sue lorem ipusm dolor sue lorem ipusm dolor sue</div>
```

i just want to change the img to video. as you can see from the fiddle. my id test is fit to screen but the video that i want to input is not.not even fit screen not even responsive. how can i make a video fullscreen that fit to screen and responsive

the result in codepen like this with video

http://codepen.io/vicario/pen/jqBNLN

still have more hight so not fit on screen

Comment: It doesnt work like that.... You can't fit height as you would deform the video size and that is a wrong idea as all computers has different screen size.. your video might end up with more height than width for screens with greater height than width... yes, there are some!

Comment: can u suggest the other way to make a  video with fit screen sir? like jquery plugin or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/6mscbLer/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <video src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28831/Typer.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://www.webestools.com/page/media/videoTag/BigBuckBunny.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.wrapper video {
    object-fit: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: nice one sir for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css file

```
video{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpjqh822/12/

**Edit:**

I think I should note that in your case you have to add `min-width: 100%;` to the video so the video will never change it's size and will be still 100% of the users screen (depending on parent div - **parent div that contains video must be set to 100% too, without any margins or paddings**)

Comment: nope solved sir. if you make container bigger. it didnt fit.